# React Native Center align Body Title text

Tags: react-native, native-base

How can I center a title text in native base?

```
<Header>
  <Left style={{flex:1}}>
    <Button
       transparent
       onPress={() => NavigationService.navigate('Home')}
    >
      <Icon name='arrow-back' />
    </Button>
    </Left>
    <Body style={{flex:1}}>
      <Title>Vacancy Snapshot</Title>
    </Body>
</Header>
```

The result above is a text align to the right.
[image]
If I include the Right tag `<Right style={{flex:1}} />` after the Body, it center the text, but doesn't display the whole text:
[image]

Comment: remove `flex:1` from <Right>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by including the `<Right style={{flex:1}}/>`, the title text will be centered. and increase the `flex` to `3` from `1` so that the full length of the text can be displayed, like this:

```
<Header>
  <Left style={{flex:1}}>
    <Button
      transparent
    >
      <Icon name='arrow-back' />
    </Button>
    </Left>
    <Body style={{flex:3}}>
      <Title>Vacancy Snapshot</Title>
    </Body>
    <Right style={{flex:1}}/>
</Header>
```

i've also included an expo snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@kenmistry/nativebase-example-1) for further experimentation. have fun!

Comment: Work like a champ. Thank you!